# Why is a call option called 'call', and put option called 'put'?

Tags: definition

I'm asking about etymology, and not [what these options are](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/7smiok/eli5_what_are_people_in_the_stock_exchange/dt6qyuo/). The answers beneath don't feel convincing; can't 'call' and 'put' be interchanged in them? I'll abbreviate Call Option to CO, and Put Option to PO. From [Quant SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/33349/31928):

> Not as much on origin of this, but some analogy that I find helpful:
>
> **Call** - think of an open auction when bidders call out their prices for an auctioned item. So with a call option you've got a privilege to
>   *call the strike price*, effectively having a right **to buy** the underlying asset.
>
> **Put** - think that you own a privilege to *put the asset for sale at the strike price*, effectively having a right **to sell** the
>   underlying asset.
>
> Mind that for an option buyer this is optional to exercise it, yet for
>   the option writer it's an **obligation** to transact, should the buyer
>   opt to exercise it.

But can't I be said to:

1. for a CO, "put" (to the CO seller) to buy the security at the strike price (for a CO)?
2. for a PO, "call" (to the CO seller) to sell the security at the strike price?

From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-call-option-called-as-such-as-opposed-to-a-put-option-What-is-the-etymology-behind-such-names#):

> When you buy a call and exercise it you are receiving stock that you have "called" up from the person that sold you the call, the right to buy.
>   When you buy a put you have purchased the right to sell the stock, or "put it" to the person who sold you the put.

Again, can't I say that a:

3. CO is when a CO seller "puts" the call option to the CO buyer?
4. PO is when a PO buyer is "calling" the PO seller to buy the security from the buyer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an etymology Q&A site.

Comment: I’ve always understood a call option as an option to call on the option seller for the underlying (at a specified price), while a put option is an option to put the underlying to the option seller (at a specified price). That certainly seems to be the simplest explanation, though I don’t have a source for you.